# Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

Tags: json, typescript

Error when json import in typescript

error message :
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

books.ts

```
import data from './books.json';

class books{
    //...code
    constructor(){
        //...code
    }
}
```

books.js

```
"use strict";
**Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });**
class books {
    //...code
    constructor() {
        //...code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

your code

```
import data from './books.json';
```

implies you are running in a module. To run modules on browsers you need a module bundler. e.g. https://webpack.github.io/

## More

Quickstart on webpack with TypeScript https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Very late 2019 comment: browsers support ES modules just fine these days, as long as you use `<script src="..." type="module"></script>`. No need for bundling. In fact, it's entirely possible that your app both loads faster, and gets cached much better, served as regular module files instead of bundled up into a single giant wad of code. Although you almost always want to use `<script src="..." type="module" defer></script>` so that your app gets _loaded_ in parallel with the page, but doesn't _execute_ until the DOM has been fully parsed. (also: no more "putting scripts at the end of body")